# multi-threading slower than single thread?

Tags: arrays, multithreading, performance, delphi

Most of the application runtime is in this function:

```
function Panorama(var Solutions: TSolutionDynArray): Integer;
var
  I, J: Integer;
begin
  Result := 0;
  for I := Low(Solutions) to High(Solutions) do
    with Solutions[I] do begin
      Panorama := Level;
      for J := Low(FPertinentPanoramas[I, Level])
          to High(FPertinentPanoramas[I, Level]) do
        if Level > Solutions[FPertinentPanoramas[I, Level, J]].Level then
          Panorama := Panorama + 1
        else
          Panorama := Panorama - 1;
      Result := Result + Panorama;
    end;
end;
```

where

```
  TSolution = record
    Level, Panorama: Integer;
  end;
  TSolutionDynArray = array of TSolution;
```

`FPertinentPanoramas` is a multidimensional array of Integers (initialized once and then remains constant)

Computation of `I, J` is **not** dependent on any other `I, J` -- this problem can therefore be easily parallelized: simply add parameters `LowSolutions` and `HighSolutions` and modify the loop to

```
for I := LowSolutions to HighSolutions do
```

E.g.: instead of 1..1000, multithread 1..250, 251..500, 501..750, 751..1000

However, for whatever reason, single thread is always faster than multithreading (threads are created once and reused -- `ExecuteAnonymousThreads; Event.WaitFor;`):

```
type
  TAnonymousThread = class(TThread)
  private
    FEvent: TEvent;
    FProc: TProc;
  protected
    procedure Execute; override;
    procedure SetProc(const Proc: TProc);
  public
    constructor Create(const Proc: TProc = nil);
    property Proc: TProc write SetProc;
  end;

var
  AnonymousThreads: array of TAnonymousThread;
  Event: TEvent;

procedure InitializeThreads(const N: Integer);
procedure ExecuteAnonymousThreads;

implementation

var
  FCriticalSection: TCriticalSection;
  FCounter: Integer;

procedure Counter;
begin
  with FCriticalSection do begin
    Acquire;
    FCounter := FCounter - 1;
    if FCounter = 0 then
      Event.SetEvent;
    Release;
  end;
end;

constructor TAnonymousThread.Create(const Proc: TProc = nil);
begin
  inherited Create;
  FreeOnTerminate := True;
  FEvent := TEvent.Create;
  SetProc(Proc);
end;

procedure TAnonymousThread.Execute;
begin
  while not Terminated do begin
    FEvent.WaitFor;
    FEvent.ResetEvent;
    if Assigned(FProc) then
      FProc;
    Counter;
  end;
end;

procedure TAnonymousThread.SetProc(const Proc: TProc);
begin
  FProc := Proc;
end;

procedure InitializeThreads(const N: Integer);
var
  I: Integer;
begin
  Event := TEvent.Create;
  FCriticalSection := TCriticalSection.Create;
  SetLength(AnonymousThreads, N);
  for I := Low(AnonymousThreads) to High(AnonymousThreads) do
    AnonymousThreads[I] := TAnonymousThread.Create;
end;

procedure ExecuteAnonymousThreads;
var
  I: Integer;
begin
  FCounter := Length(AnonymousThreads);
  Event.ResetEvent;
  for I := Low(AnonymousThreads) to High(AnonymousThreads) do
    AnonymousThreads[I].FEvent.SetEvent;
end;
```

The obvious question is why is multithreaded performance so inferior, and is there something that can be done to improve this?

EDIT:

- I have previously attempted to use non-anonymous threads with Execute hardcoded to the function, but there were no noticeable improvements, so I have posted the simpler anonymous code
- While TParallel.For performs horribly **within** the function loop, I have now had encouraging results using it **on** the function:

```
  TParallel.For(Low(A), High(A),
    procedure(I: Integer)
    begin
      Panorama(SolutionsPool[I]);
    end);
```

EDIT:
OTL `Parallel.ForEach` outperforms `TParallel.For` by approx. +10%

EDIT:
The following can outperform `TParallel.For` by over 100%, but is highly dependent on the value of `N` (obviously, ideally `(HighA - LowA + 1) mod N = 0`):

```
    uses
      System.Classes,
      System.SysUtils,
      System.Threading;
    
    const
      PARALLEL = 25;
    
    type
      TParallelFor = class(TThread)
      strict private
        FThreadPool: TThreadPool;
      public
        constructor Create; overload;
        constructor Create(CreateSuspended: Boolean); overload;
        destructor Destroy; override;
        procedure ParallelFor(const LowA, HighA: Integer;
            const Proc: TProc<Integer>; const N: Integer = PARALLEL);
      end;
    
    constructor TParallelFor.Create;
    begin
      Create(False);
    end;
    
    constructor TParallelFor.Create(CreateSuspended: Boolean);
    begin
      inherited;
      FThreadPool := TThreadPool.Create;
    end;
    
    destructor TParallelFor.Destroy;
    var
      ThreadPool: TThreadPool;
    begin
      ThreadPool := FThreadPool;
      inherited;
      ThreadPool.Free;
    end;
    
    procedure TParallelFor.ParallelFor(const LowA, HighA: Integer;
        const Proc: TProc<Integer>; const N: Integer = PARALLEL);
    
      function Task(const L, H: Integer; const Proc: TProc<Integer>): ITask;
      begin
        Result := TTask.Create(
          procedure
          var
            I: Integer;
          begin
            for I := L to H do
              Proc(I);
          end, FThreadPool);
      end;
    
    var
      H, I, L, X: Integer;
      Tasks: array of ITask;
    begin
      if Terminated then
        Exit;
      X := (HighA - LowA + 1) div N;
      SetLength(Tasks, N);
      for I := Low(Tasks) to High(Tasks) do begin
        L := LowA + X * I;
        if I < High(Tasks) then
          H := LowA + X * (I + 1) - 1
        else
          H := HighA;
        Tasks[I] := Task(L, H, Proc);
        Tasks[I].Start;
      end;
      TTask.WaitForAll(Tasks);
    end;
    
    end.
```

A longer `Proc` tends to benefit from a higher `N` (presumably due to overheads?), so an array of 10000 should be parallelized more than if that array had been of mere 100

The above does NOT mean `N` should be ridiculously high

Comment: Note that it takes time to create threads and wait for them. How long the parallel code last in your tests?

Comment: Also note that you *are* serializing some of the code between threads (ie, via the critical section), which will slow things down a little bit. Consider using an atomic/interlocked counter instead.

Comment: In any case, just throwing more threads at a given code does not magically make that code run faster, the code needs to actually be designed/optimized for multi-threading to see speed boosts. Also, have a look at using [`TParallel.For()`](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.Threading.TParallel.For) instead of manual threads. See [Using TParallel.For from the Parallel Programming Library](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Using_TParallel.For_from_the_Parallel_Programming_Library)

Comment: Jérôme Richard: this is why threads are therefore created ONCE then reused

Comment: Remy Lebeau: afaik the code is easily multithread-able, simply run slices of the the original loops in parallel; i should have perhaps mentioned having tested TParallel.For, performs horribly

Comment: Multiple threads competing for the same cache lines may be a factor here.

Comment: 500 - Internal Server Error: this is a simple multidimentional array in integers; "cached" = result of lengthy calculation done once then saved in an array, to be reused rather than recalculating dynamically every time -- HUGE performance gains

Comment: Apart from multithreading - quadratic algortihm in `Panorama` doesn't look optimal - for example, with sorted array one could use binary search to get change of Panorama value  quickly (of course, I don't know all the details)

Comment: MBo: you may be misunderstanding the algorithm? ```Solutions``` holds building levels; ```FPertinentPanoramas``` holds levels of other buildings ```J``` in "range" of building ```I``` (range is dependent on ```Level```); for each such building-in-range there is a panorma bonus, positive if building ```I``` has high ```Level``` than ```J```, negative otherwise. if you have algorithmical optimization suggestions i'd love to hear them.

Comment: @hundreAd OK, now I see that treated items `Solutions[FPertinentPanoramas[I, Level, J]]` represent just subset of the full list

Comment: Don't update your counter for each item. By doing this you are basically forcing other threads to wait for the one that is updating the counter to finish. Try updating the counter for every 50 or 100 items. This will reduce the number of times you are doing synchronization between threads.

Comment: SilverWarior: ```FCounter``` is the number of threads still working, this is the way to wait for all threads to finish, see "Waiting for a Task to Be Completed" in help. This is NOT updated for every item, but for every "slice" of the array processed concurrently (e.g. items 1..1000 with 4 threads, so thread #1=1..250, #2=251..500, ... , #4=750..1000, proceed when all are finished); WaitForMultipleObjects on all FEvents should be equivalent in effect (but perhaps not in performance?)

Comment: try add System.NeverSleepOnMMThreadContention := true;
May be it set to false, its slow multithreading memory allocation

Answer (score -1):

In general, I will answer the question: why does one thread work faster than if it is divided into several.
The processor performs one task at a time, it cannot do two tasks at a time. Windows too, but it simulates multithreading. It seems to us that the programs work at the same time, in fact they work in turn.
Your threads are not running at the same time, but in turn. Conditional: Each thread in turn executes one command.
You just split the stream into several and added synchronization between them (I didn’t go into details in your code, it doesn’t make sense for this). No matter how hard you try, your code will be executed at least at the same speed (highly doubtful). Faster - never. If you can do it faster, then it can be implemented in one thread (it will be even faster). If I were you, I would try to make as few threads and synchronization between them as possible.
In the new books, I have not seen a description of the operation of the computer, in the old books it is described.

Assembly language for Intel processors Kip.R.Irwin //Page 71

Comment: You are disregarding MULTI-core architecture (if e.g. 12 cores, single thread can provide only ~8% of total cpu power): while core #1 runs 1..250, core #2 can run -- in effect -- IN PARALLEL on 251..500; for certain, TParellel.For on Panorama executes faster than simply single-thread-ing it

Comment: I tried to find information about this. The book that I read is old and there is no information about the kernel. Whether there is a difference in operation between a single-core processor and a multi-core one, I cannot say, this is only an assumption based on observations - this is known only to the manufacturer. I think it's a marketing ploy. I can't prove you "wrong", just as you can't prove me "wrong". There is no correct answer here. And the fact that the divided program flow is slower than one remains.
Now I assumed that the kernels are the stages of the conveyor.

Comment: I won't pretend of be of any significant knowledge on the subject, however TParallel.For loop on Panorama is faster than single-thread: task manager also shows cpu utilization of above 8% (again, I have 6 cores for 12 logical processors)

Comment: Does it run faster but use more CPU time? I won't pretend to know how the CPU works either, but I think you can allocate the same amount of time to one process (8%) and it will again be faster. I don't know how to manage CPU time occupancy, I know that it is possible to give priority to a thread. Since we're talking about CPU time allocation: Are there methods for control other than giving priority?

Comment: Legat: single thread uses a single core, so for 12 cores max is 8% of cpu, has nothing to do with priorities (priority = what to prefer running when the system is overloaded). if you want higher cpu usage, the only way it multi-threading (or run the same single-threaded application several times i guess...)

Comment: Interesting. I experimented with streams. As you said, one thread uses the CPU at a certain proportion (25% for my CPU with 4 threads), but the load of the threads themselves is unpredictable. When one stream: 1 stream - 70%; 2 stream - 40%; the rest - 0%. When three streams are created: 1 stream - 100%; 2 stream - 30%; 3 and 4 stream - 70%. When the CPU has enough time, all threads run at the same speed. It turns out if the program works in only one thread, and the CPU has 30 threads of 0.5 GHz. Then the program will hang very much, and the CPU will be idle.

Comment: Weird and very interesting. I think anyway Windows will distribute this thread to the remaining 14 cores, and everything will work well, although now I strongly doubt it. I'll try to find more literature on this subject. Old books no longer correspond to reality, you need to look for new ones.